# Handling collection in asp.net core using EditorFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-mvc

In ASP.NET Core application i have the following code to handle string collection

```
  @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Detail.AccountNumbers.Count; i++)
  {
     <input asp-for="Detail.AccountNumbers[i]" class="form-control" />
  }
```

I want to refactor the above code to use `EditorFor`. So i created a partial view `_AccountNumberEditor.cshtml` and put it in `EditorTemplates` and then refactor the code as below.

```
  @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Detail.AccountNumbers.Count; i++)
  {
     @Html.EditorFor(x=>x.Detail.AccountNumbers[i],"_AccountNumberEditor")
  }
```

**_AccountNumberEditor.cshtml**

```
    @model string
    <input asp-for="?????" class="form-control" />
```

Since the account number is just a `string`, i have model of type `string`. What would be the value of`asp-for` attribute so that it would create correct name and id attribute

Comment: Not related, but `EditorTemplates` should be named the same as the class name (i.e. `AccountNumber.cshtml` assuming that is the name of the class), and then its just `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Detail.AccountNumbers)` (no loop). You can always use `@model string @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m, new { @class = "form-control" })`

Answer (score 0):

i found it. I just have to use `@Model` when model is of type string

```
<input asp-for="@Model" class="form-control" />
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms#expression-names